# Range Find replace VBScript excel compiler error missin instructions

Tags: excel, replace, vbscript, compiler-errors

I'm trying to get a find & replace VBA script(in Excel) to work, but i get the error that it needs instructions. im quite new to scripting/vba so dont mind the eaze of the question :)

```
Worksheets("General").Columns("C").Replace _
What:="Y", Replacement:="N", _ 
SearchOrder:=xlByColumns,  MatchCase:=True
```

The error pops up after the **"what:"**

it states that its a compiler error

my source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194086.aspx

[THE ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcpwI.jpg)

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: it is one statement. So the error occours in the whole.

Comment: the error: http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/Logon/code/code_800A0400.htm

Comment: `VBA` and `VBScript`are different things. The Microsoft resource, you linked, is for `VBA` while your error is from `Windows Script Host` while interpreting `VBScript`.

Comment: If you're getting this error it suggests that you're writing `vba` code into a `vbscript`.  What environment are you working in? As this code will only work as-is from inside the Excel VBA IDE

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737%28v=office.14%29.aspx -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737%28v=office.14%29.aspx#odc_Office14_ta_GettingStartedWithVBAInExcel2010_MacrosAndTheVisualBasicEditor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get it working. i used:

```
Dim myxl
Dim mywb
Dim mysh

Set myxl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
myxl.Visible = True 
myxl.DisplayAlerts = False
myxl.EnableEvents = False

'20160412 BM open the workbook
Set mywb = myxl.Workbooks.Open(mysrcfile, True, False, , , , , , , True)

'20160523 BM open the sheet
Set mysh = mywb.WorkSheets("General")

'The parameters in the following order for: what, replacement,lookat, searchorder, matchcase
mywb.Sheets("General").Columns("C").Replace "Y", "N", 1, 2,  True 

mywb.Save
mywb.Close false
Set mywb = Nothing
myxl.EnableEvents = True
myxl.DisplayAlerts = True
myxl.Quit
Set myxl = Nothing
```

Comment: Yes, with `VBScript` you cannot use named parameters. But as it stands this answer is not useful for others than yourself since there is not enought code around. If you really wants to use VBScript, the first thing your script needs to do is getting the `Excel` application as an object. Then get the `Workbook` object. Your code starts with getting the worksheet. And it will only work if the Excel workbook is the active window, what should be avoided. So why not simply using `VBA` from within Excel? This is also documented much better than `VBScript`.

Answer (score 1):

Erase "General" and input number of the sheet. My guess is that you have a typo.
Also Erase "C" and leave number of column
I wrote this

```
Sub test
Worksheets(1).Columns(3).Replace What:="Y", Replacement:="N", searchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
End Sub
```

If you get error. It might be because there is no string containing "Y" in the column

Comment: Also note that you are looking for "Y" not "y". If you want to look for both change MatchCase:= True to MatchCase:=False

Comment: Still not working. im getting the following error: <b> http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/Logon/code/code_800A0400.htm<b/> i also made sure there is a string in the colomn.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code. Check if you've inserted a new module. If you are writing the code into one of the pages it might produce an error. In VBA click insert a module and paste the code I or colegue beneath have. Then run it.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Worksheets("General").Columns("C").Replace What:="Y", Replacement:="N", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns,  MatchCase:=True
```

It could be your _ are not correctly placed.

Comment: Not working eighter. Am i missing out something? do i need to declare a variable somewhere?